# Are the variables in Erlang are (or can be called) reference variables?

Tags: erlang

so for instance

```
f() -> 3.
x() -> F = fun() -> f() end,
       A = f(),
       B = ?MODULE:f(),
       C = F().
```

right after `F` hash been defined, a new version of code for `f()` is defined as follows 
`f()-> three` and loaded.
What would be the value of `C`.

Answer (score 0):

if you cant read the whole answer
**Update**
context: Answer is "three"

**EDIT:** Sorry The answer is misleading, 
here is the right answer:
As the F is just defined but the function is not evaluated,
since we are making a fully qualified call before evaluating F; 
the new code will be loaded and the value will be "three"

So, i posted the question in erlang mailing list, i got the reply with this answer

*Funs are always bound to the code they are initially loaded from. Only name look-ups are affected by code loading AFAICT.
This has been a source of exceptions in our previous development, because the first time you load new code, F is still valid, but the second time you load new code, the old code is purged and F is now invalid. Any call to it will generate an exception.
We ended up wrapping our needs for lambdas in a module with state instead. Not the most elegant, but allows us to get "dynamic lambdas." If all you need in the fun is module:function, you can use a tuple for that instead of a fun.
Sincerely,
jw*

Answer (score -1):

In your example, only the value of B will be 'three'. The newest version of a module is only executed when an external call to the module is made. This makes hot code upgrades an atomic operation, you're either executing old or new code, never both.

Comment: So what is your conclusion? There the (new)code will be loaded after B (i got this), but what about the value of C?